# Why is "addExplosionForce" adding a continuous force?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a function that is supposed to fire a bullet and do the recoil, but the recoil adds a continuous force.

```
private void OnGunShot()
    {
        Instantiate(gunData.muzzleFlash, muzzle.transform);

        Vector3 aimDir = (transform.forward).normalized;
        var myNewBulletInstance = Instantiate(gunData.bulletPrefab, muzzle.position, Quaternion.LookRotation(aimDir, Vector3.up));
        myNewBulletInstance.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = aimDir * gunData.bulletSpeed;

        rb.AddExplosionForce(gunData.recoil, muzzle.position, 0, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);
        gunParentRb.AddExplosionForce(gunData.recoil, muzzle.position, 0, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);

        input.shoot = false;
    }
```

In that bit of code, I had the line
`rb.AddExplosionForce(gunData.recoil, muzzle.position, 0, 0, ForceMode.Impulse);`

that instead of applying a one time force, adds a continuous force, even with `ForceMode.Impulse`. This conflicts with the script that  controls how the gun moves and in the end, makes the gun shake when I fire, never returning to the original position.

I know that the issue is with this bit of code and nothing from the other script because when I removed the other script, the gun just slid backwards forever.

Is it because my guns rigid body has no drag? I don't think so because when I increased the drag, the gun returned to it's original position but while unsmoothly shaking the entire time.

Also, the way my other script works is that it has the gun and the gun parent (both of which have the script applied to them) and it lerps both their positions to the gun position (which is tied to the player object)

Comment: Well the short answer would be it is repeatedly added because the code is repeatedly running

Comment: But the specific line (and everything with it in the function) only work when told to

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by lerping both the parent and the child objects velocities to 0 with this bit of code in the update function

````
        gunParentRb.velocity = Vector3.Lerp(gunParentRb.velocity, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Time.deltaTime * 10);```
````